# is there any way to access dataframe out side of if-block?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-sql-2.4.1v, with java8.
I have to check some condition in if block , if condition met then I need to add another field to dataframe ... and I need to access that field out side of if-block , how to handle this scenario.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("Jose", "BLUE"),
        ("lI", "BrOwN")
    ],
    ["name", "eye_color"]
)

val colorLst = Seq("BLUE")

if(df.col("eye_color").isin(colorLst ){
    val new_df = df.filter(df.col("eye_color").isin(colorLst ))
}

//here how can I access new_df i.e. outside of condition
```

> Is it a good practice to assign back to the existing df ? i.e.   df=
>   df.filter(df.col("eye_color").isin(colorLst ))
>
> What is the industry practice??

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty DataFrame variable before the start of the if block and assign the value of new_df to it. This is the industry standard in these cases.

On the other hand, in your case, I don't feel any need to use the if condition. You can straightaway assign the value 
`val new_df = df.filter(df.col("eye_color").isin(colorLst ))` to the `new_df` and then use the if condition on `new_df` if necessary.

Comment: Then you can use the first approach and create an empty DataFrame variable. You can use the variable to handle the if block logic.

Answer (score 1):

is the line `if(df.col("eye_color").isin(colorLst )` compiling for you?

above code should not compile as `df.col("eye_color").isin(colorLst )` return Column and if needs a boolean.

You can try following way:
First apply filter and get the filterd datframe.
`val new_df = df.filter(df.col("eye_color").isin(colorLst:_*))`

Now you can use if condition like below

```
val df1 = if(new_df.takeAsList(1).size == 0) df else new_df
```

Hope it helps.